# Keyboard input lagging in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, lag

I have a strange problem with my newly installed Linux Mint 13 Cinnamon.
Sometimes, while I'm typing, the system does not register some of my inputs. And sometimes, it gets 'stuck' on a key and repeats it 4-5 times and sometimes ignores 3-4 of my key presses after.

That's the best way I can describe it. Any way to debug this? Any fixes?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you've provided. It *seems* like you may be using a *cordless* keyboard. If so

- try using a different (`USB`) port
- move the "dongle" (if possible)

In *any* case

- If using a `USB` keyboard, move to a different (`USB`) port
- ALWAYS ensure that your keyboard is the ONLY device plugged into the (`USB`) port you're using

Answer (score -1):

Try turn off USB port's power save option by setting `autosuspend` to -1.

Here's a comprehensive tutorial on how to achieve this (check #7) : 
[How to Configure Power USB Ubuntu](http://www.ehow.com/how_7536984_configure-power-usb-ubuntu.html)

Comment: Link doesn't work, it redirects to another article